# How to get the content off an JS variable to an input

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im having some problems with getting my content from an JS variable to transport it to an span html,in this variables are the name of the file and the size of the file,also i want it to be in a html tag cause whit that i can send it to php and store it in a database,here is the code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit_enviar_dados'])){    
    $flag=false;
    $flag_referencia=false;
    $material=$_POST['material'];
    $layers=$_POST['layers'];
    $camadas=$_POST['camadas'];
    $quantidade=$_POST['quantidade'];
    $dimensao_x=$_POST['dimensao_x'];
    $dimensao_y=$_POST['dimensao_y'];
    $cor=$_POST['cor'];
    $superficie=$_POST['superficie'];
    $slikscreen=$_POST['slikscreen'];
    $nome_produto=$_POST['nome_produto'];
    $tamanho=$_POST['tamanho'];
    

    
    /* Existiu um erro */
    if($flag==true){
    
    }else{
     $inserir="INSERT INTO produto_pcb                  (material,layers,camadas,quantidade,dimensao_x,dimensao_y,cor,superficie,slikscreen,nome_produto,tamanho) VALUES ('".$material."','".$layers."','".$camadas."','".$quantidade."','".$dimensao_x."','".$dimensao_y."','".$cor."','".$superficie."','".$slikscreen."','".$nome_produto."','".$tamanho."')";
        
        $result=mysqli_query($ligax,$inserir);
    }
    if($result==1){

?>
<script>
alert("Dados inseridos com sucesso.");
</script>
<?php } else {
?>
<script>
alert("Dados não inseridos!");
</script>
<?php
}
    
}
?>
<div class="tabela">
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="file_form"  >
    <input type="file" class="file-input" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".zip"hidden>
    <span class="material-symbols-rounded">upload</span>
    <p>Add gerber file</p>
  </form>


<div class="file-info" style="display: none;">
<div class="let"><form action="" method="POST">
  <p>Nome do ficheiro: <span name="nome_produto" class="file-name" id="nome_produto" disabled></span> (<span name="tamanho" class="file-size" id="tamanho" ></span> KB)</p>
  
  </div> 
</div>
                <p><input required type="submit" name="submit_enviar_dados" value="Registar"></p>

</form>

<script>
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const fileInput = form.querySelector(".file-input");
const progressBar = document.querySelector(".progressbar");
const counter = document.querySelector(".counter");
const fileInfo = document.querySelector(".file-info");
const fileNameElement = document.querySelector(".file-name");
const fileSizeElement = document.querySelector(".file-size");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
var nome_produto = document.getElementById("nome_produto");
var tamanho = document.getElementById("tamanho");


// Function to handle file input change
const handleFileInputChange = (file) => {
  const fileName = file.name;
  const fileSize = Math.round(file.size / 1024); // Convert bytes to KB

  // Display file info
  fileNameElement.textContent = fileName;
  fileSizeElement.textContent = fileSize;
    
    nome_produto.textContent = fileName;
    tamanho.textContent = fileSize;
</script>
```

I tried already to pick with the php the name and size when the form is called but dind´t work.

Comment: `<span>` tags do not get sent to the server when the form is POST'd.  You could use an `<input type='text'` but make sure it's not `disabled` as disabled inputs also don't get sent.   My suggestion is to use a `<input type='hidden' name='tamanho' id='tamanho'/>` *and* a `<span id='tamanho_display'` (or similar).  Then set `tamanho_display` `.textContent` *and* `tamanho` but use `.value = fileSize`

Comment: `the name of the file and the size of the file`...this will be transmitted to PHP automatically when you upload the file - you don't need to put them into a separate `input` in the form. You seem to have two separate forms though, which doesn't make a lot of sense. You can only submit one form at a time!

Comment: Also, can't see where `handleFileInputChange` is called (and missing `}` so will be giving a script error)

Comment: Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. in a free text field, anything with a `'` in the input value (such as a name like `O'Reilly`)  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `O`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Answer (score 2):

**Proposed Answer:**

To achieve transferring content from a JavaScript variable to an HTML input, you can follow these steps:

1. **HTML Structure:**

   - Ensure your HTML structure has elements for displaying the file name and size.
2. **JavaScript Function:**

   - Implement a JavaScript function to handle file input changes.
   - Inside this function:

     - Retrieve the file name and size from the file object.
     - Update the corresponding span elements with these values.
     - Assign the file name and size to the JavaScript variables (`nome_produto` and `tamanho`).
3. **Integration with PHP:**

   - Upon form submission, ensure that the PHP code retrieves the values from the input fields properly.
   - Use these values in your PHP logic for database insertion.

**Code Implementation:**

```html
<!-- HTML Structure -->
<div class="file-info">
  <p>Nome do ficheiro: <span id="nome_produto"></span> (<span id="tamanho"></span> KB)</p>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
const fileNameElement = document.getElementById("nome_produto");
const fileSizeElement = document.getElementById("tamanho");

// Function to handle file input change
const handleFileInputChange = (file) => {
  const fileName = file.name;
  const fileSize = Math.round(file.size / 1024); // Convert bytes to KB

  // Update span elements with file info
  fileNameElement.textContent = fileName;
  fileSizeElement.textContent = fileSize;

  // Assign values to JavaScript variables for further use
  nome_produto.textContent = fileName;
  tamanho.textContent = fileSize;
};

// Example usage: calling the function with a file object
const exampleFile = { name: "example_file.zip", size: 10240 }; // Example file object
handleFileInputChange(exampleFile);
</script>
```

Ensure that the JavaScript function `handleFileInputChange()` is triggered whenever the file input's value changes. Upon form submission, access `$_POST` values in your PHP script to proceed with database operations.

This approach ensures synchronization between JavaScript variables and HTML elements, facilitating data transfer and storage within PHP.